# Formik in React Container Pattern

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using React Container Pattern for a project with Formik. If I want to pass some props from "Container component" to "Presentational component" how can I catch those props in Presentational Component?

//CONTAINER COMPONENT

```
    render() {
return (
    <CreateColorContainer
      key="CreateColor"
      name="Add Color"
      {...this.state}
    />
);
```

}

//PRESENTATIONAL COMPONENT

```
   <Formik
  initialValues={}
  validationSchema={}
  onSubmit={(fields) => {}}
>
  {(props) => {
     const { touched, errors, setFieldValue } = props;
    return (
      <div className="page-wrapper">
        //Props i want to use here
      </div>
    );
  }}
</Formik>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding your question, but wouldn't you just pass anything from the container component to the presentational component as props? The presentational component just accesses what it needs via the passed props. Perhaps question/issue would be more clear with a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: inside the <Formik></Formik> the props i am getting are only formik props. I want to know how can I use my own props inside here?

Comment: Well, I suppose any props passed to the component rendering `Formik` will still be in scope within the `Formik` JSX.

Comment: I know. But I am unable to use my own props here. Pobably I have some syntax error. I am looking for a working example code...

Comment: I think it's really simple, the component rendering the `Formik` component is the one you need to reference the props of. I ***am*** assuming this component to be the presentational component you speak of. If you post complete code though we can stop making assumptions about your code structure.